# How to select the correct src from srcset with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have a srcset on my page

```
<img src="bg__x-large.png" srcset="bg__small.png 900w, bg__med.png 1200w, bg__large.png 1920w">
```

This is used by a parallax script, which right now just reads the src attribute

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')' );
```

to set this as the background image.

How can I read the correct src from the srcset with jquery?

Comment: @newnoise there are multiple images in `srcset` which one you want to get; ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `.currentSrc` *property* (as opposed to `.src`) of the image to determine the active "src":

jq:
`$(this).prop('currentSrc')`

vanilla:
      `this.currentSrc`

see [mdc's HTMLMediaElement.currentSrc docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentSrc) for more info.